# Django with JWT. How to use both ? Use a JWT token auth mechanism from restframework-jwt to access django-admin

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I have the following setup: I have Django and Vue.js app in a frontend. When user logs in a frontend he gets a JWT and next requests have token in a headers and everything is fine here. But when I point to the app which has an admin interface /admin/filer/ it appears that I'm not logged in, and I need to login using default login mechanism. Here is my config

Even if I send a request with a signed JWT - it still not works

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
            'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
            # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        ],
        'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
            'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
        ],
        'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': [
            'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'
        ],
        'ORDERING_PARAM': 'sort',
    }
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        'reversion.middleware.RevisionMiddleware',
    ]
    JWT_AUTH = {
        'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': timedelta(days=7),
        'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION':False,
        'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': timedelta(days=7),
        'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'apps.auth_module.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',
    }
```

Comment: Some link for some solution, still not get it https://gist.github.com/elnygren/830e560e9a167464774693cbd55389c9

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287426/django-with-jwt-how-to-use-both-use-a-jwt-token-auth-mechanism-from-restframe

Comment: https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt/issues/120